# How to download image from firebase-storage to display inside collectionViewCell's Imageview(Swift)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell, firebase-storage

I have uploaded an image into firebase-storage and saved the downloadURL into a key/value pair inside of my database. I've written a code that is suppose to display the image(s) inside of a collectionView, once the data has been retrieved, if the url is valid. The code is executed at cellForItemAt since the the collectionView housing the pictures is embedded inside of another collectionView(Which will be called Main or MainCV to prevent confusion).

To solve the problem, I have tried to reload the collection view's data inside of MainCV, as well as trying to testing the code on a view controller with just an ImageView(not successful).

```swift
// function to display images
private func icon(_ imageURL: String) -> UIImage {
        //print("imageURL is \(imageURL)")
        let url = URL(string: imageURL)
        var image: UIImage?
        var imageData:Data?
        if url == nil {
            print("URL is \(imageURL)")
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_person_outline_white_2x")
        } else {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error")
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    imageData = data
                    image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                }
                }.resume()
            return image ?? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_person_outline_white_2x")
        }
    }
```

CellForItemAt block of code

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
        let imageOption = self.imageData[indexPath.row]
        cell.iconImageView.image = icon(imageOption)
        return cell
        //imageData is an array with empty values that is populated with database values and subsequently reloaded
    }
```

The intended result as I said earlier is to display the images from firebaseStorage inside of the collectionView. My code does not render any errors, but always returns the default image as well as printing the imageURl which I confirmed to be the accurate http for the image I'm trying to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn something about asynchronous programming.

Your function returns immediately, but `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!)` takes some time. Timeline:

1. image = nil
2. start fetching data
3. return image ?? defaultImage
4. fetching data finished (after function returned -> image data lost)

Instead of returning immediately, provide closure taking image as a parameter into your function:

`private func icon(_ imageURL: String, closure: (UIImage) -> Void)`

and update your code to

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("error")
        closure(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_person_outline_white_2x"))
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        imageData = data
        image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        closure(image)
    }
}.resume()
```

The closure itself can be a function accepting the image as an argument and setting this image **asynchronously** to your collection view cell

Also, you want to provide some default or loading image before your image is loaded. Or use ActivityIndicator.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did help!! I'm currently learning about async functions and the developer notes are not always clear to me. My only question is whether or not there's a faster way to pull the data from the database.

Comment: My app has recently started crashing do to my UIImage being called from a background thread. I'm looking threw the developers notes and it appears that my actions were correct but I get error

Comment: All UI stuff has to be called from the main thread. If you start a dataTask, the response will be called on a background thread. To get it back on the main thread, wrap it into 
`DispatchQueue.main.async { your code goes here }`